# Prove that $a_n=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{2^k}$

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $a_n$ which is number of ordered divisions of the $n$-set in which the order of the elements in the blocks is irrelevant but the order of the blocks is important $(a_2=3: \left\langle \left\{ 1,2\right\} \right\rangle , \left\langle \left\{ 1\right\}, \left\{ 2\right\}  \right\rangle, \left\langle \left\{ 2\right\}, \left\{ 1\right\}  \right\rangle)$.
>
> Prove that $a_n=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{2^k}$ where $0^0=1$.

I was able to prove that: $$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n \choose i}a_{n-1}$$
where $a_0 = 1$ but I don't know how to obtain a pattern independent of $a_{n-1}$ to get $a_n=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{2^k}$. 
Can you help me with it?

### Update

from answer I got:
$$a_n = (2^n-1)(2^{n-1} - 1) ... (2-1) = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(2^k-1)$$
but how is it related with given infinity series?

### Update 2

I checked in wolfram that:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n}(2^k-1) =(-1)^n (2;2)_n$$
but
$$ \frac{1}{2} \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{k^n}{2^k}= \frac{1}{2} \Phi \left(\frac{1}{2},-n,0\right)$$
I don't know these functions but it seems that it is not the same.

Comment: Fix your recurrence, and use it to find $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n/n!$

Comment: I get that formula for $a_n$ if $a_0=1$ and the recurrence for $n\ge1$ is $$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}a_k$$ Is that the correct recurrence?

Comment: If you show your derivation of the recurrence, I will undelete my answer.

Comment: I am afraid that your recurrence is wrong.

Comment: @MP3129: please, when you edit, don't just add a space to get attention to your question. Instead, you could have fixed the recursion, and even shown how you arrived at that recursion.

Comment: As people have mentioned, your recurrence is not correct. Your recurrence does give the answer that Mostafa Ayaz gives, but since your recurrence is wrong, the answer does not match that expected in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If what you proved is correct, you can write$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {n \choose i}a_{n-1}=\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i}-1\right]a_{n-1}=\left[2^n-1\right]a_{n-1}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but in your answer is also $a_{n-1}$ and I don't know how to reduce it. Can you explain it?

Comment: $a_n = (2^n-1)(2^{n-1} - 1) ... (2-1) = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(2^k-1)$ - I don't see how it is equal for given series..